# CSS Centering div on other

Tags: html, css

I am trying to find the best way to center one div over another which is using the 'top' and 'left' CSS components.
When resizing the browser window the circle should always be in the center of the box, however moves slightly off horizontally when scaling

Here is the code I am using;
https://codepen.io/EarlGrey8/pen/LYVOQrY

```
body {
    background-color: #908787;
}


.banner {
    position: fixed;
    width: 101%;
    margin: -1%;
    height: 35%;
    background-color: #76568e;
}

.moduleContainer {
    position: absolute;
    font-family: 'Bellota', cursive;
    background-color: #e2e2e2;
    top: 25%;
    left: 20%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border-color: #cacaca;
    width: 60%;
    height: 400px;
}

.moduleInner {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: -130px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70%;

}

.moduleImage {
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-color: #908787;
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    top: -130px;
    left: 33%;
}

<body>
    <div class="banner"></div>

<div class="moduleContainer">
    <div class="moduleImage"></div>
    <div class="moduleInner"></div>

</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To center the circle on any screen. Try the following CSS.

```
.moduleImage {
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Comment: Oh dear. That is so simple, a little embarrassing xD Thank you for the swift answer!

Answer (score 0):

Change `.moduleImage`'s `position`, `transform` property.

```css
body {
  background-color: #908787;
}

.banner {
  position: fixed;
  width: 101%;
  margin: -1%;
  height: 35%;
  background-color: #76568e;
}

.moduleContainer {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'Bellota', cursive;
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
  top: 25%;
  left: 20%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border-color: #cacaca;
  width: 60%;
  height: 400px;
}

.moduleInner {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: -130px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70%;
}

.moduleImage {
  position: absolute; /* change */
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #908787;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  top: -130px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%); /* change */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bellota&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="simple.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="banner"></div>

  <div class="moduleContainer">
    <div class="moduleImage"></div>
    <div class="moduleInner"></div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use calc css3 `calc` 
see example:

```css
body {
 background-color: #908787;
}


.banner {
 position: fixed;
 width: 101%;
 margin: -1%;
 height: 35%;
 background-color: #76568e;
}

.moduleContainer {
 position: absolute;
 font-family: 'Bellota', cursive;
 background-color: #e2e2e2;
 top: 25%;
 left: 20%;
 border-style: solid;
 border-radius: 20px;
 border-color: #cacaca;
 width: 60%;
 height: 400px;
}

.moduleInner {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 top: -130px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 70%;
 
}

.moduleImage {
 position: relative;
 border-radius: 100%;
 background-color: #908787;
 height: 250px;
 width: 250px;
 top: -130px;
 left: calc(50% - 125px); /* just this line changed */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bellota&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="simple.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="banner"></div>

<div class="moduleContainer">
 <div class="moduleImage"></div>
 <div class="moduleInner"></div>
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

everything is same.

just in `.moduleImage` class i changed left property to `left: calc(50% - 125px);`

125px is half of element width.

Answer (score -1):

update your code by

```
.moduleContainer {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: absolute;
    font-family: 'Bellota', cursive;
    background-color: #e2e2e2;
    top: 50%;
    left: 20%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border-color: #cacaca;
    width: 60%;
    height: 400px;
}
.moduleInner {
    display: inline-block;

    height: 70%;
}
.moduleImage {
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-color: #908787;
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
}
```

I hope this work